# Why all Linux terminals hang if running program with higher priority

Tags: linux, multithreading, terminal, centos

I'm running some console program that uses 2 threads - main and worker. Main thread starts worker, waits for user input ("Press ENTER to exit"), then terminates worker and exits. Worker thread spins 100% of time processing data.

All works fine if running that program from local terminal console as is:

`./MyProg`

But things go strange if running it with CPU affinity and higher priority:

`taskset -c 8 chrt -r 20 ./MyProg`

In this case terminal becomes significantly less responsive and finally hangs (stops updating screen and reacting on key press) after some amount of time (2-3 minutes). My program doesn't hang, it continues to process data correctly, just cannot quit due to inability to react on user keyboard input. Also there is no any other programs running (except few terminal instances).

The other embarrassing thing is that ALL (running and newly opened) terminals start to experience same problem. In same time Gnome GUI doesn't! It works flawlessly, opens any menus/dialogs/GUI programs without any visible delay.

So the questions are:

- Why Linux terminals have such strange behavior?
- Are all terminal instances sharing some global resource, e.g. thread or sync object?
- How this can be avoided (OS tweaks, program redesign)?

Distributive used is CentOS 6 x64, `uname -a` results are:

```
Linux leopard 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

CPU is Intel Xeon, number of logical cores is 12.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what terminal emulator did you use? gnome-terminal? xterm? Did you try different ones?

Comment: Standard Gnome terminal

Comment: This is somewhat expected.  Since a thread runs in the same process ID, it will take more of the CPU time slice than the rest of the process itself.  You might try running the program with a higher priority using nice to set the priority when you start it instead of setting the priority with a thread.

Comment: @calmond There is no setting priority to thread, process level only.